# I am trying to make a function that "syncs" a list with only the numeric, non-blank lines of a text file

Tags: python, list, text, python-3.x

I am writing a program that reads numbers from a specified text file (ignoring blank and non-numeric lines), each of which are on their own line, and writes each one to a list as an individual entry. Basically, the function doesn't just append the contents to the list, but syncs the list with the contents.

A few things I have tried:

```
y = []
#x is textfile, y is list variable
def parse_file(x,y):
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if (line.strip()).isdigit():
                y = [int(line.strip())]

parse_file('text.txt',y)
```

and:

```
y = []
#x is textfile, y is list variable
def parse_file(x,y):
    z = []
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if (line.strip()).isdigit():
                z.append(int(line))
    y = z
    print(z)

parse_file('text.txt',y)
```

Both of these result in `y` remaining empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `y` remains empty is because you are modifying it in the **local** scope, not the global scope. Since you start off with `y` as an empty list anyways, how about just defining it when it's actually going to contain something? Here's a working example:

```
def parse_file(x):
    y = []
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if (line.strip()).isdigit():
                y.append(int(line.strip()))
    return y

y = parse_file(x)
```

Comment: Your example results in y only having one entry - the last line of the text file. If my text file is:
50

40

30
20
10

y = parse_file('text.txt')
print(y)

results in [10]

Comment: @Kevin this was a flaw in your original code, then, it seems -- which i've corrected.